# Compare percentage increase/decrease with different sample sizes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, percentage

I have a question here and in need of expert advices :).

Consider:

work_week = 52.
Total no. Samples = 360
Green = 73%
Red = 0%
Yellow = 27%

work_week = 53.
Total no. Samples = 650
Green = 66%
Yellow = 29%
Red = 4%

The number samples almost doubled up from work week 52 to work week 53.

Is there any way to say the percentage of green / yellow / red increased or decreased ?

How to say whether the number of Green or Yellow or Red increased / decreased ? The sample size is different?

Answer (score 1):

Given the percentages and the absolute numbers you can compute absolute numbers of counts and you can then do $\chi^2$- and Binomial inference on those numbers.

**Expl.** Is the decrease in Green significant? We have `.73 * 360 = 263` Green in week 52 and `.66 * 650 = 429` in week 53. In R:

```
> prop.test(x = c(263, 429), n = c(360, 650))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(263, 429) out of c(360, 650)
X-squared = 5.0244, df = 1, p-value = 0.02499
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.009859771 0.131251340
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.7305556 0.6600000
```

So yes, the decrease in Green was significant with $p = .024$.

One Caveat: There is a slight imperfection due to rounding: 73% out of 360 may be 262 or 263 or 264. Rounding looses information. So if you can, try to obtain absolute numbers in the first place.